# Best practice for async map moving

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

If I move a map in WP7 and initiate a web service call with every move, how should I handle multiple web calls being called every second. When i drag a map around, there are a bunch of event calls to MapDragEvent. What is a good solution to dealing with this issue. If I attach a http call to the map drag event..should i look for a thumb up event? or anything like that? I can't seem to find a good combination of events.

Comment: With Reactive Extensions (It's included with WP) you could do something like mapDrags.Throttle(Timespan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(x => ..handle drag..); But I'm neither a Maps nor an RX expert.  http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post I wrote about Bing Maps and moving around the map and getting more data

http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-many-pins-can-bing-maps-handle-in.html

Comment: This looks like a great approach, wish this was something more native to the control. Seems like it's something you would do often with a map control!